# Django. Загрузка нескольких изображений через Админку к статье

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Django 3.

Как сделать загрузку нескольких изображений к статье через Админку.
Что бы на страницы со статьей размещались от 1 и до N-го количества фотографий.

Answer (score 0):

самый простой вариант создай `Inline` форму для редактирования изображений и прикрепи ее к основной, после этого админка автоматически позволит тебе сохранять несколько изображений

предположим у тебя модели:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name='Заголовок', max_length=255)


class ArticleImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Картинка')
```

Тогда в admin.py

```
class ArticleImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ArticleImage


class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ArticleImageInline,
    ]
```

И все - сохраняй столько изображений сколько тебе нужно.